# Passport local strategy and cURL

Tags: node.js, curl, express, git-bash, passport.js

I would like to test my node.js + express + passport.js test application (RESTful) with CURL. My code:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// Define the strategy to be used by PassportJS
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") // stupid example
            return done(null, {name: "admin"});

        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }
));

// Serialized and deserialized methods when got from session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

// Define a middleware function to be used for every secured routes
var auth = function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.send(401);
    else
        next();
};

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/test', auth, function(req, res){
    res.send([{name: "user1"}, {name: "user2"}]);
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

Calling /test with curl and

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/test"
```

returns "Unauthorized" (this is correct so far).

Calling /login (POST) with curl and

```
curl --data "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:3000/login
```

works. But at the next request my login was "forgotten".
Is this because curl can't handle sessions? Is there any workaround?
Is my procedure correct for a RESTful application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make `curl` save cookies when you log in with

```
curl --cookie-jar jarfile --data "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:3000/login
```

Read the stored  cookies when accessing `/test`:

```
curl --cookie jarfile "http://localhost:3000/test"
```

Some modifications to the app itself were needed before it worked on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) with Node.js v0.10.26 and Express 3.5.0. I generated a new Express app with `express --sessions nodetest` and edited the code in `app.js` to be as you see below. Once I had the dependencies installed I ran the app and it worked with the  `curl` commands.

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

// Define the strategy to be used by PassportJS
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") // stupid example
            return done(null, {name: "admin"});

        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }
));

// Serialized and deserialized methods when got from session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

// Define a middleware function to be used for every secured routes
var auth = function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.send(401);
    else
        next();
};

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/test', auth, function(req, res){
    res.send([{name: "user1"}, {name: "user2"}]);
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

### curl script

```
#!/bin/sh
# curl-login.sh
rm jarfile
echo --- login
curl --cookie-jar jarfile --data "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:3000/login
echo --- test
curl --cookie jarfile "http://localhost:3000/test"
```

### Console log with curl output

```
$ node app &
$ sh curl-login.sh
--- login
POST /login 200 2ms - 21b
{
  "name": "admin"
}--- test
GET /test 200 1ms - 60b
[
  {
    "name": "user1"
  },
  {
    "name": "user2"
  }
]
```

Note the use of

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
```

in `app.js`. Sessions **did not** work without the above two lines.

The code in your question also lacks the part where you create an HTTP server but I assume that's just a copy-paste issue; I'm referring to

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work.
Regarding curl manual the command is `curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt http://www.example.com`. Do I have to use this command for every call? So: `curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt --data "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:3000/login` and then `curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt http://localhost:3000/test`? I tried this. When calling /test I still get: Unauthorized. :(

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about how `--cookie-jar`/`-c` worked (for some reason I thought it made the jar R/W when in fact it only writes  cookies and doesn't read them). I've edited my answer; please try the new version.

Comment: Post the `jarfile` you get and the output from  `curl -v --cookie jarfile "http://localhost:3000/test"`. Perhaps some changes need to made in your node.js app.

Comment: Where is 'jarfile' saved?

Comment: In whatever directory you are in when you run `curl` in the terminal. Type `cat jarfile` and post the output.

Comment: @mosquito87: I edited the answer to suggest changes to the app itself.

Comment: Now it works. Yesterday I was so frustrated that I switched to basic auth (self built). Now I have a working solution (yours), I can use it. Thumbs up & thanks for your effort!