# Passportjs, Express, and Curl not working

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to set up the local authentication strategy with sessions using Passportjs and Express. I have the following `User.js`

```
var redis = require('redis');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var r = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost', {no_ready_check: true});

var findOne = function(username, callback){
  user = new UserSchema(username);
  callback(user.err, user);
  get_fields = [
    "user:" + username + ":password_hash",
  ];
  r.mget(get_fields, function (err, replies) {
    if (err){
      callback(err, null);
    } else if (replies === null || replies[0] == null) {
      callback(null, null);
    } else {
      password_hash = replies[0]
      console.log("findOne Called: " + replies[0])
      callback(null, new UserSchema(username, password_hash))
    }
  });
};

var UserSchema = function (username, password_hash) {
  this.username = username;
  this.password_hash = password_hash;
  this.validPassword = function(password) {
    if (this.username === "test"){
      console.log("Tested password")
      console.log(this)
      console.log(this.password_hash)
      console.log(this.password_hash === "test")
      return this.password_hash === "test"
    }

    if (this.password_hash === undefined || this.password_hash === null){
      return false;
    }

    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password_hash);
  };
};

module.exports = {
  findOne : findOne, 
  UserSchema : UserSchema,
};
```

And the following entry point `app.js`

```
var User = require('./User');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require('redis');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var app = express();

var r = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost', {no_ready_check: true});

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'DEADBEEF0FEEBDAED1DEADBEEF',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true, 
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne(username, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      console.log(user)
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
  console.log("Deserializing User")
  User.findOne(username, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Server Alive');
});

var auth = function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.sendStatus(401);
    else
        next();
};

app.get('/test', auth, function (req, res) {
  r.get("user:test:password_hash", function(err, reply){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.send(reply)
  });
  // res.send('Server Alive');
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'));

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

var httpServerListener = httpServer.listen(8080, function() {
  var host = httpServerListener.address().address;
  var port = httpServerListener.address().port;

  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Cannot serve on port without root privileges:');
  console.error('sudo node index.js');
});

var httpsServerListener = httpsServer.listen(8443, function() {
  var host = httpsServerListener.address().address;
  var port = httpsServerListener.address().port;

  console.log('Secure app listening at https://%s:%s', host, port);

}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Cannot serve on port without root privileges:');
  console.error('sudo node index.js');
});
```

I'm trying to login with the following cURL command, but I get an `Unauthorized` response. The curl commands are as follows:

```
$ curl -X POST -c jarfile -b jarfile --data "username=test&password=test" -v http://localhost:8080/login

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 27
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
* Added cookie connect.sid="s%3A18MNffLkHj5OwjSazA-S1IDDXSdx5JPb.FWzFtqEt97D6DG7zVaocBoEH%2BX%2Fi0nynrb8tslojpIQ" for domain localhost, path /, expire 0
< set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3A18MNffLkHj5OwjSazA-S1IDDXSdx5JPb.FWzFtqEt97D6DG7zVaocBoEH%2BX%2Fi0nynrb8tslojpIQ; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 18:32:07 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Unauthorized

$ curl -X GET -c jarfile -b jarfile -v http://localhost:8080/test

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A18MNffLkHj5OwjSazA-S1IDDXSdx5JPb.FWzFtqEt97D6DG7zVaocBoEH%2BX%2Fi0nynrb8tslojpIQ
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 12
< ETag: W/"c-4G0bpw8TMen5oRPML4h9Pw"
< Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 18:32:37 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Unauthorized
```

Any suggestions for how to modify this code would be helpful. I've been trying to follow the suggestions as described by this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252226/passport-local-strategy-and-curl), but have had little success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to comment out this snippet at the top of `findOne` in `User.js`:

```
user = new UserSchema(username);
callback(user.err, user);
```

Once this block is commented out, it works as expected.